# How to fix a diagnostic error in flutter?

Tags: gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, system.diagnostics

When I run the application gradle is failing to build

> Compiler message:
>   file:///C:/Users/Wellick/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_sticky_header-0.3.4/lib/src/widgets/sticky_header_layout_builder.dart:147:16:
>   Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter
>   type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
>    - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart'
>   ('file:///C:/Users/Wellick/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
>   Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to
>   'DiagnosticsNode'.
>         context: context);
>                  ^ Compiler failed on C:\Users\Wellick\Desktop\flutter\rapidinho-master\lib\main.dart
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\Users\Wellick\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>     line: 665
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileflutterBuildDebugArm'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Users\Wellick\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 24s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you please add a coding example?

Comment: also post your 'flutter doctor -v' output

Comment: That's [an issue in the flutter_sticky_header plugin](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_sticky_header/issues/28) on v0.3.4. Updating to v0.4.0 should fix it according to the linked Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue was due to the previous version 0.3.4 to be exact, the [issue was reported in GitHub](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_sticky_header/issues/28) and the fix is to upgrade the version to 0.4.0. Currently, the [latest version 0.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header/changelog) is more stable than the previous versions.